# regular replace in visual studio: Highlight occurrences but does not replace

Tags: regex, visual-studio, replace, find

I am trying to replace `Descendants(ns + "string").First().Value` to

```
Descendants().First(x => x.Name.LocalName == "string").Value from visual studio.
```

I tried `Descendants\(ns \+ .*"\).First\(\).Value` in Search and it highlight occurrences correctly. But `Descendants().First(x => x.Name.LocalName == \1).Value` doesn't replace `\1` to `"string"`

Please suggest me what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: I thnk you mean this http://regex101.com/r/aO5dB0/4 ? Your regex isn't captured anything.

Comment: Checked http://regex101.com/r/aO5dB0/4. Getting same result Descendants().First(x => x.Name.LocalName == \1 ).Value. \1 is not being replaced with string.

Comment: Yes worked with $1. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex isn't captured anything that is you didn't include any capturing groups in your regex.

Regex:

```
Descendants\(ns \+ "([^"]*)"\).First\(\).Value
```

Replacement string:

```
Descendants().First(x => x.Name.LocalName == $1).Value
```